# Spring mvc interceptor exception

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor

My project is baded on spring mvc, and I wrote a interceptor to intercept request, I want to get parametrts from request, the follows is my code:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    HandlerMethod maControl = (HandlerMethod) handler;  
    Method pmrResolver = (Method) maControl.getMethod();  
    String methodName = pmrResolver.getName(); 
        ....
}
```

but now it throws a exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler cannot be cast to  org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod
```

What is the cause of the Exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply means that `handler` isn't an instance of `HandlerMethod`, so the cast fails. Check before casting as follow:

```java
if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
    HandlerMethod maControl = (HandlerMethod) handler;  
    Method pmrResolver = (Method) maControl.getMethod();  
    String methodName = pmrResolver.getName(); 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I use the interceptor as a privilege interceptor. and I want to intercept all request, so if the 'handler' isn't an instance of 'HandlerMethod', how can I deal with this case? and when the 'handler' is an instance of 'DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler', can you help me?

Comment: How did you resolve this? Seeing same issue in  my project